# Run first request of Logstash http_poller input plugin immediately after Logstash startup

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using Logstash with the [http_poller input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http_poller.html) to fetch some data from a HTTP url. The `input` section of my Logstash config file looks like this:

```
input {

    # regularly pull data via http
    http_poller {
        urls => {
            my_service => {
                method => get
                url => "http://my.service.com/data"
                auth => {
                    user => "some_user"
                    password => "some_password"
                }
            }
        }
        request_timeout => 30
        interval => 300
        metadata_target => "http_poller_metadata"       
        type => "my_type"

    }
}
```

The setting `interval => 300` means that the request is started every 300 seconds (or 5 minutes). However, this also leads to the fact that after starting Logstash and waiting for the pipeline to get ready, it waits the whole 300 seconds before running the request for the first time.

I would rather like Logstash to start the first request immediately after Logstash and the pipeline are ready and then wait another 300 seconds before the next request.

Can this be achieved somehow?